# Reading realtime tweets from a set of twitter accounts

Tags: streaming, twitter, real-time

I have a group of twitter accounts and want to stream latest tweets from that set of accounts in my web application?

I couldnt find any API method matching that requirement.

How can this be implemented without having rate limiting issues?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api).

Site Streams which is in Beta might be of interest

> Site Streams, a new feature on the
>   Streaming API, is now available for
>   beta testing. Site Streams allows
>   services, such as web sites or mobile
>   push services, to receive real-time
>   updates for a large number of users
>   without any of the hassles of managing
>   REST API rate limits. The initial
>   version delivers events created by, or
>   directed to, users that have shared
>   their OAuth token with your
>   application. The following events are
>   streamed immediately, and without rate
>   limits: Home Timelines, Mentions
>   Timelines, User Timelines, Direct
>   Messages, Mentions, Follows,
>   Favorites, Tweets, Retweets, Profile
>   changes, and List changes.

Comment: "The initial version delivers events created by, or directed to, users that have shared their OAuth token with your application." What i want is to read public tweets, not only from accounts who have shared their Oauth tokens.

Comment: What about? Streaming API: Public statuses from all users, filtered in various ways: By userid, by keyword, by random sampling, by geographic location, etc.